# ActiveRecord/SQL include associated model conditionally without joining

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my `RequestsController#index` I've got a simple query that returns 47 rows (the actual query includes a bunch of other associations and conditions that aren't relevant here):

```
requests = current_contact.requests.includes(:hub_post).limit(20)
```

I've got the following models:

```
class HubPost < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :contact
    has_many :requests, dependent: :destroy
end

class Request < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :contact
    belongs_to :hub_post, optional: true
end
```

Within HubPost I've got the following methods:

```
def shared_by(count=2, excluded=nil)
    ids = Request.where(hub_post_id: self.id, completed: true).pluck(:contact_id)
    ids = ids.keep_if { |id| id != excluded.id } if excluded.present?
    ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(Contact.where(id: ids).limit(count), serializer: PortalContactSerializer).as_json.shuffle
end

def shared_by_count(excluded=nil)
    ids = Request.where(hub_post_id: self.id, completed: true).pluck(:contact_id)
    ids = ids.keep_if { |id| id != excluded.id } if excluded.present?
    Contact.where(id: ids).count
end
```

In its current form, this code represents a pretty serious N+1 problem. This endpoint takes on average 2,000ms to respond. Now I could easily solve the N+1 problem by changing `.includes(:hub_post)` to `.includes(hub_post: [requests: [:contact]])`. The problem now is this query pulls thousands of request rows from the database and instantiates them in memory as ActiveRecord objects, which is an even worse problem to have.

Ideally I only want to include requests where `completed = true` and `contact_id != current_contact.id` and I want to `limit` it (the number of included rows) to 2 or `count` if count is defined so that I'm not grabbing thousands of records.

To make things just a bit more complicated, I don't want to `join` the association because I then loose some of the requests. I want to grab all the current_contact's requests even if that request doesn't have a hub_post or it has one but the hub_post doesn't have any other requests.

I tried using `includes` with a `where` statement and a `references` statement but that seems to just do a join, like below. This query only returned 18 rows when I'd expect it to return all 47.

```
requests.includes(hub_post: [:requests]).where(hub_post: { requests: { completed: true } }).references(hub_post: [:requests])
```

As far as I know there is no way to `includes` an association conditionally judging by the other questions I've seen on the subject. What I would like to know is if it's possible to solve the N+1 problem in performant way that doesn't cause memory consumption issues.